# How to edit a specific pattern according to an array of patterns?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file containing the string `"proto"` which is repeated 384 times.  Each `"proto"` should be edited according to 384 different labels existing in another textfile. For insance, if the content of the second text file is `a, sp, ..` (each label exists in a newline), so in my textfile the first "proto" should be changed to `"a"`, the second to `"sp"` and so on. How should I do that?
The original file is a 384 repetitions of :

```
~o <VecSize> 39 <MFCC_0_D_A>
~h "proto"
<BeginHMM>
     <NumStates> 5
     <State> 2
        <Mean> 39
          0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
        <Variance> 39
          1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
     <State> 3
        <Mean> 39
          0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
        <Variance> 39
          1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
     <State> 4
        <Mean> 39
          0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
        <Variance> 39
          1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
     <TransP> 5
      0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
      0.0 0.6 0.4 0.0 0.0
      0.0 0.0 0.6 0.4 0.0
      0.0 0.0 0.0 0.7 0.3
      0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
<EndHMM>
```

and the second file contains 384 labels, such as: `a, ap, k12, sp, ...` So as you see, I have just one form of `"proto"`. I hope it is now clear.

Comment: The word "pattern" is highly ambiguous (it could mean string or regexp or ...) so never use it in the context of software. It sounds like you are attempting to replace each occurrence of a string named `proto` with other strings. What if `protozoan` was in your input file - would the `proto` part of that be replaced or not. Post some sample input and expected output and include interesting edge cases like that as it's always trivial to replace what you do want replaced but much harder to NOT replace strings you don't want replaced.

Comment: Hello Ed, thank you for taking the time, I have just the string as "ptroto", not any combinational form of it. The file is quite large and I don't know if it is possible attach it here.

Comment: Absolutely do NOT attach it here, but do post a small REPRESENTATIVE sample input set (10-15 lines or so) that contains the cases that will be difficult for a tool to get right.

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry to reply late, I edited the question just now.

Comment: The solution you need depends on the possible values of the other 380 labels that you haven't shown us. At least tell us if they are all alpha-numeric or what? If they can contain a backslash or an ampersand then the solution you have chosen will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming textfile with replacement patterns has exact 384 lines you can use this awk command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[++i]=$0; next} /proto/{sub(/proto/, a[++j])} 1' replacement.txt file.txt
```

Comment: @KianStar I see you went ahead and selected an answer without posting any sample input and expected output. Since that means no-one has a chance to think about what you really need, I hope you have thoroughly thought it through and tested it and the various ways in which it will produce undesirable output (e.g. if an ampersand `&` character appears in `replacement.txt` or if `proto` appears twice on one line in `file.txt`, etc...) cannot occur in your real files. A script that produces the output you want from some specific input set is just the starting point for a solution.

Comment: @KianStar To be clear - I'm not saying this isn't a perfectly good answer, but so far we just don't know what the question is since you haven't provided any sample input/output so this may or may not work for you in general and I doubt if you realize what the caveats are to using it.

Comment: Hello, Im sorry to answer late, your solution worked perfectly for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|.*|s/proto/&/|' replacementFile | sed -e ':a;$!{N;ba}' -f - textFile
```

This generates a substitution command for every replacement in the replacementFile and reads this command set into sed script which has slurped the textFile into memory.

N.B. This assumes that there is a replacement for every pattern in the textFile.